# Is it possible to call method from inside of service/object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to trigger a service-method from inside the service. I have tried `simperiumBucket.make` and `this.make`. Neither work.

```
service('simperiumBucket', function($localStorage, $rootScope, simperiumCred){
    $rootScope.$on('authSuccess', function(scope,response){
        simperiumBucket.make('first')
    });
    return{
        make: function(name){
        //here is the code i wish to run
        }
    }
}).
```

How can I trigger the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
service('simperiumBucket', function($localStorage, $rootScope, simperiumCred){
    var self = this;

    self.make = function(name) {
        //here is the code i wish to run
    };

    $rootScope.$on('authSuccess', function(scope,response){
        self.make('first');
    });

    return {
        make: self.make
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reorder your code a bit:

```
var ret = {
    make: function(name){ ... }
};

$rootScope.$on('authSuccess', function(scope,response) {
    ret.make('first');
});

return ret;
```